# Merge two binary vectors

Tags: matlab, binary

I need to combine the binary representation of 6 and 7 together:

```
bin1 =  fliplr(de2bi(6));
bin2 =  fliplr(de2bi(7));

bin1 =

     1     1     0


bin2 =

     1     1     1
```

after the combination the number should be

```
bin3 = 110111
```

Does anyone have any idea on how to do this?

Comment: why not simply concatenate them? `bin3 = [bin1, bin2]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested you can just concatenate them

```
bin3 = [bin1, bin2]
```

However, if you really want them packed together without spaces you can do it like this:

```
bin3 = num2str([bin1, bin2]);
bin3 = bin3(bin3 ~= ' ')
```

If you want to turn them in to a number now you can use `str2num()`

Comment: Even shorter: `num2str(bin3, '%d')`