# Element-wise binary value concatenation of two matrices

Tags: matlab, matrix, binary, binary-matrix, binary-image

Element by element, I want to concatenate binary values from different matrices to one matrix.

For example,

```
|1 0 0|  |0 1 0|   |10 01 00|         
|0 1 1|  |1 1 0| = |01 11 10|       
|1 0 1|  |0 0 1|   |10 00 11|
```

How can this be done?

Comment: As far as I know, Matlab doesn't have the ability enter numbers in  numeric matrices using binary values. Matlab's logical matrix type only stores one bit binary, i.e. true and false. Your output matrix will either need to be numeric in which case it will be displayed in decimal or strings in which case you won't be able to use more math operations.

Comment: might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13347749/merge-two-binary-vectors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one alternative without `bin2dec` or `dec2bin` conversion

```
out = arrayfun(@(x,y) strcat(num2str(x),num2str(y)),A1,A2,'Uni',0);
```

**Input:**

```
A1 = [1 0 0; 0 1 1; 1 0 1];
A2 = [0 1 0; 1 1 0; 0 0 1];
```

**output:**

```
>> out

out = 

'10'    '01'    '00'
'01'    '11'    '10'
'10'    '00'    '11'
```

If you want it as numeric instead of string, you might do this:

```
outp = cellfun(@(x) str2double(x), out);
```

**output:**

```
>> outp

outp =

10     1     0
 1    11    10
10     0    11
```

Answer (score 3):

I would store the output matrix as a decimal matrix and convert to binary strings when accessing elements.

To concatenate the elements, treat each input matrix as a binary digit

```
A1 = [1 0 0; 0 1 1; 1 0 1];
A2 = [0 1 0; 1 1 0; 0 0 1];
output = A1 * 2^1 + A2 * 2^0;
output_str = arrayfun(@dec2bin, output, 'UniformOutput', false);
```

`output` will be a double matrix

```
[2,  1,  0;
 1,  3,  2;
 2,  0,  3]
```

`output_str` will be a cell array of strings

```
['10', '1',  '0';
 '1',  '11', '10';
 '10', '0',  '11']
```

Comment: @Michael Glad to be of help!

Comment: Also, if you don't mind you might have to add `'uni',0` to the end of `arrayfun` to avoid the error.